# webRTC with local network

Tags: php, html, video

need some help here.

i am creating a html5/php website that allow users to broadcast video using webcam to multiple users currently we are using webRTC but it is lagging if there are many users viewing the video.

I am trying to use my local pc as the server with mainly user from the intranet. can I still use webRTC to implement it? if so how do i do it?

any tutorial that i can read?

```
 var iceServers = [];

        iceServers.push({
            url: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
        });

        iceServers.push({
            url: 'stun:stun.anyfirewall.com:3478'
        });

        iceServers.push({
            url: 'turn:turn.bistri.com:80',
            credential: 'homeo',
            username: 'homeo'
        });

        iceServers.push({
            url: 'turn:turn.anyfirewall.com:443?transport=tcp',
            credential: 'webrtc',
            username: 'webrtc'
        });

        connection.iceServers = iceServers;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider using WebSockets with node.js in this instance as they will give a much better connection.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications

https://github.com/websockets/ws

Comment: thank you. i am using websocket over nodejs now.  but encounter some error will be starting a new question instead.